# Applying DCF on finding intrinsic value of Nifty50 index or any kind of stock index

Tags: market-indexes

Instead of applying DCF on stock price, I wish to apply the technique in order to find intrinsic value of a index since it resembles the behavior of the overall market. But, I'm very consumed what could the best approach be.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An index if just a collection of individual stocks - it does not have "cash flow" itself in order to to any type of Discounting Cash Flow analysis.  You can do cash flow analysis on the individual stocks and multiply by their weight in the index, but there's nothing in the index itself that would be suitable for DCF valuation.

Comment: Thanks, will try to do the same